# Drupal custom module failing to install

Tags: module, drupal-7, wsod

I have created a module on a development server (xampp) all is fine and working. However when I have move the module to my production server it fails to install properly, WSOD. From db I can see that my fields are not being created.

Drupal version 7.27 on both, both clean installs with the same dependencies installed.
Nothing in apache error log.

Grateful for any tips.
Mathew

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to find out what the error message is, WSOD doesn't tell us anything. Here's info on how to do that: https://drupal.org/node/158043

Answer (score 1):

ok just incase this helps someone else further down the line - this was an issue with different versions on PHP on the two servers one had 5.3 the other 5.5. One supports short form arrays [] and one does not which was my problem.

Would i have been able to resolve this from PHP logs?